# How to display multi character unicode emojis in Overleaf LaTex?

Tags: unicode, latex, emoji, emoji-tones

So apparently Overleaf now can [render emojis using packages of Noto Color Emojis](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-2019-upgrade-january-2020), where you can use `{\NotoEmoji \symbol{"1F343} \symbol{"1F338} }` to input an emoji with corresponding unicodes.

My question is how to input complex emojis that are composed of multiple emojis? For example, [this one](https://emojipedia.org/family-woman-woman-boy-boy/) ‍‍‍, the unicode is `U+1F469‍ U+200D U+1F469‍ U+200D U+1F466‍ U+200D U+1F466`.

I've tried combinations like

`\symbol{"1F469‍200d1f469200d...1f466}`
`\symbol{"1F469 200d 1f469 200d...1f466}`
`\symbol{"1F469} \symbol{"200d}...\symbol{"1f466}}`

But none of them works.

Comment: The emoji are treated as a TeX font. It sounds like you want to overlay characters in that font. There are various ways to do this. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21644/how-do-you-superimpose-two-symbols-over-each-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to concatenate them. Here's the solution that I tried in Overleaf and it worked fine.

```
{\Large 
\NotoEmoji

% family emoji
\symbol{"1F468}\symbol{"200D}\symbol{"1F469}\symbol{"200D}\symbol{"1F467}\symbol{"200D}\symbol{"1F466}
}
```

**Expected Output**

‍‍‍ [Family: Man, Woman, Girl, Boy](https://emojipedia.org/family-man-woman-girl-boy/),

You can use the same trick for Emoji Skin Tone Modifiers in Overleaf where the modifier comes right after the emoji Unicode.

```
{\Large 
\NotoEmoji

% Waving Hand emoji
\symbol{"1F44B}%

% Waving Hand: Light Skin Tone 
\symbol{"1F44B}\symbol{"1F3FB}
}
```

Expected Output

Here's the [Overleaf Project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/dctbpvvhsgjq) page about Displaying Color Emojis in Latex that you can check out.

**Updated 2020-11-28 : Adding emoji as an image in Latex**

Since you mentioned adding emojis as images, I'm also including my solution for that.

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% change font size here
\includegraphics[height=12]{family-man-woman-girl-boy.png}
```

The image can be downloaded from [EmojiPedia](https://emojipedia.org/family-man-woman-girl-boy/).

Comment: Thanks man. I ended up using the small images but this is helpful!

Comment: Anytime! Since you mentioned small images, l added an image option too which let you change the font size of the image.